# Create user Variable in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I have create user variable in Jenkins by passing this git command

```
git rev-list --count master
```

the result of this command I should save into $Variable , then I will use that variable to my job.

```
VAR=$(git rev-list --count master)
echo ${VAR}
```

I will use $VAR variable wherever I want. I have used this but didnt worked properly.

```
$VAR
```

How to achieve it Jenkins (Build Environment). Suggest me thanks

Comment: Please see the [envInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Environment Injector Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

- Go to the /job//configure screen
- In Build Environment section check "Inject environment variables to the build process"

You can also execute a script there.

Comment: I used  envInject plugin . But I got this error.          [EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
Executing /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/code/src/commitscount.sh'.
[CodeJob] $ /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/code/src/commitscount.sh
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
[EnvInject] - Script executed. The exit code is 128.
[EnvInject] - Fail the build.